# Java Возврат неправильного числа

Tags: java

Строка лишь один раз возвращает отрицательное число. Чего не хватает чтобы возвращала при каждом вводе отрицательно числа в if (ln < 0 );

```
Scanner len = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean goodln = false;
Scanner in;
int ln = 0;
while (!goodln) {
    try {
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ln = in.nextInt();
        goodln = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Вводить можно только целое число!!!");

    }
}
if (ln < 0) {
    System.err.println("Число должно быть положительным!!!");
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ln = in.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Внести `if` в цикл `while`?

Comment: Текущий код позволяет ввести только одно число. Соответственно и результат выводится только один раз. Не хватает цикла для ввода большего количества чисел.

Answer (score 1):

Условие находится вне тела цикла и вызывается всего один раз, после того как отработает while. Нужно поместить if в тело цикла while.

Comment: если просто перенести if(ln < 0) Ничего не происходит при запуске, Т.е. просто пропускает его.

Comment: Если *просто перенести* **куда**?

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны внести `if (ln < 0)` в цикл `while`. Однако вам следует еще менять значение флаги `goodln` на `false` в `if`-лупе . Тогда будет зацикливание.

```
     if (ln < 0) {
                System.err.println("Число должно быть положительным!!!");
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                ln = in.nextInt();
                goodln=false;
            }
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе. А то задолбался уже перебирать все подряд)

Answer (score 0):

У вас проверка на положительность происходит вне цикла, для того чтобы код заработал надо поместить `if(ln < 0)` в цикл `while(!goodln)`.

Я переписал ваш код так чтобы он работал и немного дополнил:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = readIntFromSysin();

        System.out.println("\n" + "The number is: " + result);
    }

    private static int readIntFromSysin()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer:");
        do {

            try {
                number = in.nextInt();

                if(number < 0)
                    System.out.println("Only positive integers are allowed, please try again:");
                else
                    return number;
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("Only integers are allowed, please ty again:");
                in.next();
            }
        } while(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо - тоже как вариант.

Answer (score 0):

судя по коду, вам надо чтобы было введено целое-положительное число. вот вам готовое решение

```
int number;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive number!");
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That not a number!");
        sc.next(); // this is important!
    }
    number = sc.nextInt();
} while (number <= 0);
System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + number);
```